# Angular Firebase service properties instantiated/null for different components

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I have an Angular service that uses Firebase. The service is used by more than one component. When one component uses the service (dashboard.component.ts uses it in onSubmit()), it takes the data and pushes it to Firebase. When another component uses it (student-ordered-escorts.component.ts also uses it in onSubmit), the escortList variable in the code below is not instantiated, is undefined, when used in newEscort().

Service code

```
import { Injectable, } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Escort } from '../model/escort.model';

@Injectable()
export class EscortService {

  escortList : AngularFireList<any>;
  selectedEscort : Escort = new Escort();

  constructor(private firebase : AngularFireDatabase) { }

  getData(){
    this.escortList = this.firebase.list('something');
    return this.escortList;
  }

  newEscort(escort : Escort){

    if(escort.driver == 'No driver yet' || escort.driver == null)
        escort.status = "Unassigned";
    else
        escort.status = "Assigned";


      if(this.escortList == null)
        console.log("escortList was null");

        this.escortList.push({
            driver : escort.driver,
            pickup : escort.pickup,
            dropoff : escort.dropoff,
            passengers : escort.passengers,
            no_show : false,
            status : escort.status,
            created : Date.now(),
            finished : null
        });
    }
```

dashboard.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as Chartist from 'chartist';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { EscortService } from '../services/escort.service';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';
declare var $:any;
declare var google: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'dashboard-cmp',
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'dashboard.component.html',
    providers: [EscortService]
})

export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit{

    constructor(private escortService : EscortService, private firebase : AngularFireDatabase) { }

onSubmit(escortForm: NgForm){
       if(escortForm.value.$key == null)
           this.escortService.newEscort(escortForm.value);
       else
           this.escortService.updateEscort(escortForm.value.$key, escortForm.value);
           this.resetForm(escortForm);
    }
}
```

student-ordered-escort.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { EscortService } from '../../services/escort.service';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-student-ordered-escort',
  templateUrl: './student-ordered-escort.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./student-ordered-escort.component.scss'],
  providers: [EscortService]
})
export class StudentOrderedEscortComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private escortService : EscortService, private firebase : AngularFireDatabase) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

onSubmit(escortForm: NgForm){
        this.escortService.newEscort(escortForm.value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You provide EscortService in 2 components which will create 2 instances of service, each component use difference instance.
So move your EscortService to AppModule

dashboard.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'dashboard-cmp',
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'dashboard.component.html',
    providers: [EscortService] // Delete this
})
```

student-ordered-escort.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-student-ordered-escort',
  templateUrl: './student-ordered-escort.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./student-ordered-escort.component.scss'],
  providers: [EscortService] //Delete this
})
```

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [EscortService],
  ...
})
```

And because your escortList is undefined when you try to push.
Change your service:

```
newEscort(escort: Escort) {

    if (escort.driver == 'No driver yet' || escort.driver == null)
      escort.status = "Unassigned";
    else
      escort.status = "Assigned";


    if (!this.escortList) {
      this.escortList = this.getData();
    }

    this.escortList.push({
      driver: escort.driver,
      pickup: escort.pickup,
      dropoff: escort.dropoff,
      passengers: escort.passengers,
      no_show: false,
      status: escort.status,
      created: Date.now(),
      finished: null
    });
  }
```

Comment: It's still giving me the same error: escortList is undefined.